# Why I have # in url<

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My url is like this: http://localhost:4200/#/login
And I dont have idea why my angular2 app make this, I have downloaded seed angular2-cli with template, and I cant find why I have # in my url, I look into every file, router but dont know why I have this.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the answer here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using an old Internet Explorer version. Angular forces the `HashLocationStrategy` on older browsers where the History api is not present